# Unity canvas scaler blocking GL.Vertex

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, canvas, drawing, line

So I'm drawing lines using GL in Unity. I draw those lines on my screen, and they are being drawn. However, I only see the lines once I disable the canvas scaler on the script that is providing the data for the lines.

I tried other ways of drawing the lines but nothing helped.

So the setup is as followed, I have a canvas in my scene with a canvas scaler ontop of it that scales with screen size. This canvas contains a script that provides the data (positions) for the lines. When the lines need to be drawn, it fires an event with a vector2[] with all the data that needs lines etc. I have another script on my main camera listening to this event, and when needed it draws the lines in the onpostrender. These lines are being drawn at the correct positions, but I can only see them once I disable the canvas scaler on the canvas. Here's some code:

This is the script in my scene (thats on the canvas) that fires an event with the data.

```
lock (_skeleton2D)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < skeleton.Length; ++i)
    {
        _skeleton2D[i] = new Vector2(skeleton[i].x * scaleX + _depthImageRect.anchoredPosition.x * 2, _depthImageRect.rect.height - skeleton[i].y * scaleY);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < skeleton.Length; i++)
    {
        Vector2 vector2 = skeleton[i];
        objects[i].transform.position = vector2;
    //                    _skeleton2D[i] = vector2;
    }

    DrawSkeletonRenderer?.Invoke(_skeleton2D);
```

As you can see in the end it fires the DrawSkeletonRenderer with a Vector2[] _skeleton2D. Then I have a script on the Main and only camera in the scene which is listening to this event, and when it receives the event, it updates it's own Vector2[] of skeletondata, and uses this to render the lines.

```
private void Start()
{
    _skeletonMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("UI/Default")); 
    MoveCalibrationToolManager.DrawSkeletonRenderer += receivedDrawSkeleton; 
}

private void receivedDrawSkeleton(Vector2[] skeleton)
{
    _skeleton2D = skeleton;
    isSkeletonValid = true; //TODO Turn false when not needed anymore.
}

private bool isSkeletonValid;

private void OnPostRender()
{
    if (isSkeletonValid)
    {
        lock (_skeleton2D)
        {
            drawSkeleton(_skeleton2D);
            Debug.LogError("DRAW SKELETON RIGHT NOW!");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see it eventually calls drawSkeleton which as shown below draws the lines

```
GL.PushMatrix();
_skeletonMaterial.SetPass(0);
GL.LoadPixelMatrix();

drawBone(skeleton[(int)JointType.Head], skeleton[(int)JointType.Neck]);
drawBone(skeleton[(int)JointType.Neck], skeleton[(int)JointType.LShoulder]);
drawBone(skeleton[(int)JointType.Neck], skeleton[(int)JointType.RShoulder]);
drawBone(skeleton[(int)JointType.LShoulder], skeleton[(int)JointType.LElbow]);
drawBone(skeleton[(int)JointType.LElbow], skeleton[(int)JointType.LHand]);
drawBone(skeleton[(int)JointType.RShoulder], skeleton[(int)JointType.RElbow]);
drawBone(skeleton[(int)JointType.RElbow], skeleton[(int)JointType.RHand]);
drawBone(skeleton[(int)JointType.LShoulder], skeleton[(int)JointType.RWaist]);
```

Which then calls drawBone which looks as follows:

```
if (float.IsNaN(fromJoint.x) || float.IsNaN(fromJoint.y) || float.IsNaN(toJoint.x) || float.IsNaN(toJoint.y))
 {
     Debug.Log("Joint positions for lines are null");
     return;
 }

GL.Begin(GL.LINES);
GL.Color(Color.red);
GL.Vertex(fromJoint);
GL.Vertex(toJoint);
GL.End();
```

As I said, everything is drawn but I can only see it when I disable the Canvas Scaler on the canvas that has the first script attached.

During runtime, I make a texture on which I show a feed of a 3D realsense camera. I need the skeleton to be drawn ontop of that. I make this texture the following way:

```
GameObject obj = new GameObject("Calibration View");
obj.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform, false);
obj.transform.SetAsFirstSibling();
_depthImage = obj.AddComponent<RawImage>();

_depthImageRect = obj.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
_depthImageRect.anchorMin = Vector2.zero;
_depthImageRect.anchorMax = Vector2.one;
_depthImageRect.anchoredPosition = Vector2.zero;

Quaternion transformRotation = new Quaternion(180f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
_depthImageRect.transform.rotation = transformRotation;

_depthImage.material = _depthImageMaterial;
_depthTexture = new Texture2D(RsDevice.DepthWidth, RsDevice.DepthHeight, TextureFormat.BGRA32, false);
_depthImage.texture = _depthTexture;
_depthTextureBytes = new byte[RsDevice.DepthWidth * RsDevice.DepthHeight * 4];
```

Comment: Do you really need it to be UI ? Can't you just use a lineRenderer ?

Comment: @Jichael lineRenderer is a  possible solution maybe. The reason I went with this, is because I got a sample from someone who made something like this, so I just his code as a reference. I honestly have little experience with both lineRenderer and GL. However, no matter if I go to lineRenderer or not, I would really like to know why this is happening

Comment: Then definitely go with a lineRender, you can set the number of point you want, then call lineRender.SetPosition(index, position) or set all positions at once using SetPositions([positions])

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, Monday I will try it with lineRender. Does it work simular? Can I keep this way of giving data and just adjust the GL part to LineRenderer? Meanwhile, I would still like to know the problem here. Just curious